# Search engine indexing flash website?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, indexing, search-engine

I am working on a website completely designed in Flex (flash).Can you please help suggesting whether search engines (like google/bing) can index flash content or not.If not then how do the websites made entirely in flash make themselves available on these search engines.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, Google does index Flash nowadays. [Here's an article](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=454163) on how to make Flash pages available to Google. The [Adobe SWF searchability FAQ](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swf_searchability.html) also has useful information.

The article points towards a tool called swf2html which can be downloaded from Adobe (after registering) and extracts a HTML page from the text and links in the SWF. This allows you to view the SWF the way search engines see it, and optimize accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Google's a good place to start. Several links regarding how Google indexes flash content from [this search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=flash+search+engine+index).